# Solving non-homogenus Screened poisson equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, poissons-equation

I am wandering how to solve non-homogeneus screened Poisson equaation:
$$
\nabla^2 \phi - \lambda^2 \phi=f(\mathbf{r})
$$
My function $f(\mathbf{r})$ is a constant all over the place, i denote it's velue with D, therefore $\nabla^2 \phi - \lambda^2 \phi=D$. I was able to solve this for symetric solutions in spherical coordinates with solution $\phi=a \frac{e^{-\lambda r}}{r}+b\frac{e^{-\lambda r}}{r} $. Furthermore I have boundry contition that potential $phi$ doesn't diverge at $r=\infty$.

But I don't know how to approach for non-homogenus solution. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screened_Poisson_equation) one can use Green's function approach with Green's function for this case:
$$
G=\frac{e^{-\lambda r}}{4 \pi r},
$$
but I have some problems with integration:
$$
\phi=\int d^3 r' G(r-r')f(r')=F\int_0 ^{\infty}r'^2\frac{e^{-\lambda |r-r'|}}{|r-r'|}dr
$$
But the following integal does not converge, according to all my tries. Is there any other more suitable method for Solving upper equation? Or is my Greeen's formula approach wrong or my version of Green's formula?

Comment: Why doesn't it converge? The exponential wipes out any growth of the integrand towards infinity and $1/|r|$ singularities are integrable in 3D. Also, since $f$ is constant, you might want to try the equivalent form $\int G(r')f(r-r')d^3r'$.

Comment: I think you made a good start, but the change of variables used in your final equality has to be re-examined.

Comment: @eyeballfrog In that case solution is just a constant... Since r completely dissapears from the equation

Comment: Yes, the solution is a constant.